# All the objects are visible through others

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, 3d-view, interface

I added eyebrows on his head but its also visible from through his head.

Comment: Alt + z to go back from x ray mode. ( If u have enabled x ray mode) Shift + z to go to solid mode from wireframe mode(if u r in wireframe mode). Hope that helps.

Comment: Consider adding some images to make your question more clear. Thank you : )

Answer (score 1):

You have probably enabled X-Ray mode ...

[image]